# Can I populate a page using multiple HTML documents all linked in one document?

Tags: html, sharepoint

I have built a SharePoint Site and within this site are 33 pages that have unique url's. The pages all have common elements such as a header, footer, quick links menu and banner.

The html for each page is stored locally in that page in the editor.

This means that if I wanted to make a change to a common element (i.e. add another button to the header) I would have to go in and make the change 33 times. As the pages grow, it is becoming more difficult to maintain.

My question is, would it be possible to port the code for these common elements into separate HTML files and simply link these HTML in the HTML document I upload to the page?

This would allow me to make a change once and let it propagate to the other sites. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Could you help me figure out how?

Answer (score 0):

If it's sharepoint, why not make a custom master page, or custom page template, and use them for these custom pages?